# What is the best way to traverse datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Could someone post some tips on what is the best way to loop through the dataGridView?  I've a datagridview with large number of row and want to go through and get the cell values.  I use the convention way and it take too long.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Sample code to traverse:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows) {
    object[] obj = new object[row.Cells.Count];
    for (i = 0; i <= row.Cells.Count - 1; i++) {
        obj[i] = row.Cells(i).Value; //Place your code and do type conversion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just bind your data to the `DataGridView`.  This way the collection you have will be up to date and there will be no need to traverse the `DataGridView` to get data.  See an example at [C# Tutorial - Binding a DataGridView to a Collection](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection)

Comment: This only works if you have store the data you bind to `DataGridView`. I think the asker is trying to access the data already bound.

Comment: Well if there is data in the `DataGridView`, it must have gotten there somehow (assuming the OP loaded the `DataGridView` with it).

Comment: Yeah but he'd have to store the data beforehand. Sometimes memory is expensive :P

Comment: We'll hes talking about retrieving it from the DataGridView, so sounds like its not too expensive in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to reach every cell, the fastest possible is O(n):

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        // 
    }
}
```

There are faster ways to update data however, like bindings.