# Insert datagridview data into database

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview

I have a form with a blank datagridview. What's the most effective way to get the mulptiple lines of data from the datagridview saved into the database? I've searched for tutorials and have been recommended SqlBulkCopy and a few other solutions. The aim is to use it to create invoices, so the names of the tables would need to be unique. I'm using SqlCe and C# 2010.

Comment: I haven't tried anything as of yet, for some reason bulkcopy doesn't exist in SqlCe?

Comment: Hm. I've never used BulkCopy.. The way I do it is grab each cell value individually, paramterize it and write a SQL statement using thos evalues, and iterate over each row in the DGV.

Comment: I read somewhere that way can be slow when copying lots of data. I'd say on average I'd need to insert 100 rows max. But into a unique table

Comment: would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606487/sqlbulkcopy-using-sql-ce) work ?

Comment: I have actually never tried that. I would say go for it. If you encounter difficulties, come back and ask a specific question. If that approach doesn't work for you, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997716/what-is-the-best-way-to-traverse-datagridview) for a related thread.

Comment: Could you post how you would do it as an answer? So I can see what code etc. I could use

Answer (score 0):

I refer to each cell specifically (using index), paramaterize that value and use it in an `INSERT` statement.

See here:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
 //Basic SQL INSERT statement
cmd.CommandText += " INSERT INTO ELECT_SALARY_DFRL (ELECT_XREF_SEQ_ID, EMPL_SALARY_DFRL_AMT, EMPL_SALARY_DFRL_FREQ_CD, ";
cmd.CommandText += "  FUND_SEQ_ID, ELECT_SALARY_DFRL_FUND_PCT_RT, ELECT_SALARY_DFRL_ELECT_DT, BEG_DT, END_DT)";
cmd.CommandText += " VALUES (@SeqID, @DefAmt, @Freq, @FundID, @FundPct, @Today, @begDt, @EndDT); ";

//Parameters for sql insert, from DGV.
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DefAmt", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Freq", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FundID", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SeqID", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FundPct", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Today", System.DateTime.Now());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@begDt", "19000101");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDT", "24000101");

conn.Open();
cmd.Connection = conn;


try {
         //Loop through entire DataGridView
    for (int i = 0; i <= SalaryDGV.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {
        //If row is empty, exit For Next block.
        if (BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value == null) {
            break;
        }
        //Adds value to parameters from data grid view.
        cmd.Parameters("@DefAmt").Value = SalaryDGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value;
        cmd.Parameters("@Freq").Value = SalaryDGV.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value;
        cmd.Parameters("@FundID").Value = Convert.ToInt32(SalaryDGV.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value);
        cmd.Parameters("@SeqID").Value = SalaryDGV.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value;
        cmd.Parameters("@FundPct").Value = SalaryDGV.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Error adding the Salary Deferral " + ex.Message);
}
```

Note: I used a converter so the code may not have translated the best.

Also note, I do not use this to insert 100's or thousands of rows of data, only 3-4 at a time. If there is a more efficient approach, I am not sure of it, however you asked me to post how I would do it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: No problem. If there is a faster way let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you know more than me about the subject ;)

Comment: Well as far as the most efficient I'm afraid I have never been in a scenario where my insert speed took a hit, so I am intrigued.

Comment: Its just what I read on the internet to be honest. A few people said it would work fine, others said it "takes too long" but when reading further it only took a few seconds anyway, which I could easily cope with.

Comment: Okay. Let me know how things turn out.

Comment: This is to insert into a existing table ?

Comment: Yes. This is assuming you have an existing table to save the data into. If you feel this solved your question please mark it as answered.

Comment: I wasn't very clear in the question, my mistake. I'd like to use the data to create a new table, instead of inserting into a existing table.

Comment: That's a different question. You'll have to start a new thread. Make sure you actually know what you're asking...